# Get k-th largest values

Tags: algorithm

I have some problem. I must add a lot of different values and just get only k-th largest in the end. How can I effectively implement that and what algorithm should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "must add"?

Comment: If the approach: "put them in a list, sort the list, take the top k elements" doesn't solve your problem you are going to have to elaborate a bit. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't want to store all my values and must get only k largest in the end.

Comment: Sorting is not so effective and i don't want to store all values.

Comment: did you read this question before you posted it? Look at it from our point of view, see the issue? We know nothing about what difficulties you are facing, nor what you have tried?

Comment: Do you need one number, the `k`-th largest, or you need `k` numbers, from the `k`-t largest to the largest one? Well, it's almost the same solution, but I'd like to know...

Comment: Is perhaps yours "_must add a lot of different values_" some kind of running mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Algorithm:**

1. Create a binary maximum heap, and add each one of the first `K` values into the heap.
2. For each one of the remaining `N-K` values, if it larger than the last value in the heap:

   Put it instead of the last value, and bubble it up in order to resort the heap.
3. Extract all the (`K`) values from the heap into a list.

---

**Complexity:**

1. `O(K)`
2. `O((N-K)×log(K))`
3. `O(K×log(K))`

If `N-K ≥ K`, then the overall complexity is `O((N-K)×log(K))`.

If `N-K < K`, then the overall complexity is `O(K×log(K))`.

Comment: Your answer is as good as it can be, but. Imvho you should try a bit of 'filling in the blanks' for the OP, maybe a short example of using the `heapq` module in the stdlib...

Comment: @gboffi: Which standard library? The OP didn't specify a language or environment. This answer is as good as can be given the information that the OP provided.

Comment: Oops, you're correct... for the record: I was thinkink `python`.

Comment: @gboffi: Thanks, I was asked this on a job interview once, so this is the answer I came up with. Thought about it later and realized that a simple `K`-element array could be used just as well. And since a heap is typically implemented using an array of size `O(2^m)`, it is probably advisable to use a simple `K`-element array instead (not sure if I want to add it to the answer by now).

Comment: @JimMischel: Thanks, please see additional comment above.

Comment: @barakmanos: A heap to hold k items can be implemented in an array of size k. See, for example, http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/30/a-simple-heap-of-integers/. I don't know where you got the 2^m number. Using a heap makes this algorithm O(n log k). If you use a simple array, the complexity is O(nk). *Big* difference.

Comment: @JimMischel: I got `O(2^m)` off my memory (from the days at uni, which indeed have been a long time ago)... But I disagree on the array issue. If you add the first `K` elements in sorted order, then for every other element that you add, you also add it in sorted order (using binary search), then you get the same effect as you would with a heap. This array could be qualified as a private case of a heap, but there is no need to apply any of the conventional heap operations.

Comment: @barakmanos: Before you can add the new item to the sorted array, you have to remove the smallest item and move items to make room for the new item. That takes, on average, O(k/2) time. So it takes log(k) time to find the insertion spot and O(k/2) time to insert it.

Comment: @JimMischel: Sorry, I had to think it over. You're absolutely right. Insertion into the already-full array is not going to be in `O(Klok(K))`. Good thing I didn't add that to the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

(Based on comments that you do not want to store all the numbers you have seen...)

Keep a running list (sorted) of the k largest you have seen so far.  As you get new numbers, look to see if it is larger than the least element in the list.  If it is, remove the least element and insert (sorted) the new element into the list of k largest.  Your original list of k (when you've seen no numbers) would consist of k entries of negative infinity.

Comment: Instead of keeping a sorted list, the OP should maintain a heap... or maybe a sorted list is good enough? I think it depends on `k`

Comment: You are right, really the only thing you need is to be able to extract (or read) the min efficiently and add a new element efficiently.  Sorting was just to make this "intuitively easy."

Comment: You too are right: the heap is more efficient and complicated, the sorted list is more onerous and simpler, and probably is the right fit for the OP.

Comment: @gboffi Come on, k-ary heaps are not _that_ complicated. And OP stated **a lot of different values** !

Comment: @rerito Keep it in context... If you know heaps, you'll use heaps without asking on SO.

Comment: @gboffi, I understand, but SO is a good way to learn new things and get better at programming. So your comment suggesting the use of heaps was indeed very much welcome !

Answer (score 0):

first build max-heap using those elements which is O(n) time. 
then extract k-1 elements in O(klogn) time.

Comment: Not optimal: what if n is terribly large (i.e. doesn't fit into memory) and k is very small? Instead: build a heap up to k elements and discard the minimum everytime you insert the k+1st element.